# Can't seem to get PHP login to 'stick'

Tags: php, session

```
<?php
//Login Module (Updated, isset now correct)
session_start();
if(!(isset($_SESSION['login']) && ($_SESSION['login'] != ""))) {
    include('processor/ProcessLogout.php');
} else {
    include('processor/ProcessLog.php');
}
?>
```

Problem is...it doesn't work. I can't seem to get it to validate to true T_T. I set $_SESSION['login'] in processor/assess_login.php. ProcessLog is merely a container for some divs and a form the form passes information to asssess_login (which then tells me whether a login has been successful or not). One displays a login form the other displays a logout form. Unfortunately, even though I get "Login Successful"... it's rather worrying that $_SESSION['login'] refuses to change to '1'. (That's what I do in assess_login if the login is successful. if it fails I set it to an empty string.

Now as far as I'm aware session_start() is supposed to remember this, but for some reason...it doesn't o.o; So any tips on my bug hunting

There are compilation errors and taking away the ! does infact display the alternative, so I know that bit 'is' working it just isn't evaluating to true.

Now... as for the assess_login...

```
           if ($db_found) {
        $member_username = quote_smart($member_username, $db_handle);
        $member_password = quote_smart($member_password, $db_handle);

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM $tblname WHERE username=$member_username AND passphrase=$member_password";
        $result = mysql_query($sql);
        $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

        //Validate there is a user
        if($result) {
            if($num_rows == 1) {
                session_start();
                $_SESSION['login'] = '1';
                header("location: ../login_success.php");

            } else {
                session_start();
                $_SESSION['login'] = "";
                header("location: ../login_fail.php");

            }
        } else {
            $error_msg = "Error Validating User! -1";
        }           
    mysql_close($db_handle);
    }
```

Bearing in mind it *is* buried somewhat. As I've said before I can't get the login to stick and I know I'm missing something obvious I'll be damned if I can figure out what though.

Comment: Have you verified that you're getting into the conditional where `$_SESSION['login']` gets set to `'1'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your if statement is not correct:

```
if(!(isset($_SESSION['login'])) && ($_SESSION['login'] != ""))
```

should be

```
if(!(isset($_SESSION['login']) && $_SESSION['login'] != ""))
```

Comment: Thanks...although that wasn't quite correct either. (I had been battling with this before and I thought I'd cracked it the first time around). I've edited appropriately, it needed an extra bracket at the end =P

Comment: @user1379669 You don't need the `$_SESSION['login'] != ""` in parens. I left it out for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!(isset($_SESSION['login']) && $_SESSION['login'] != ""))
```

In this code you are saying: If it is NOT set and it is NOT empty
You want it to be set and not empty:

```
if((isset($_SESSION['login'])) && ($_SESSION['login'] != ""))
```